# C++ RapidJSON Clear written string

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have the following C++ code to generate a JSON-string:

```
StringBuffer JSONData;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(JSONData);
writer.StartObject();
writer.String("hello");
writer.String("world");
writer.String("t");
writer.Bool(true);
writer.String("f");
writer.Bool(false);
writer.String("n");
writer.Null();
writer.String("i");
writer.Uint(123);
writer.String("pi");
writer.Double(3.1416);
writer.EndObject();

cout << JSONData.GetString() << endl;
//OUTPUTS:
{
    "hello": "world",
    "t": true,
    "f": false,
    "n": null,
    "i": 123,
    "pi": 3.1416,
}


JSONData.Clear();
writer.Reset(JSONData); //Wont compile
writer.StartObject(); //FAILS !Base::hasRoot_
writer.String("hello");
writer.String("world");
writer.String("t");
writer.Bool(true);
writer.EndObject();
cout << JSONData.GetString() << endl;
```

However, I want to create another JSON-object after I outputted the previous JSON data. This however returns me the error `Assertion failed: !Base::hasRoot_`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://rapidjson.org/prettywriter_8h_source.html) is the RapidJSON header for `PrettyWriter`. You can find at line 247 the error your encountering. I am no rapidJSON pro, but I think a writer only works for one object, even though your cleared it. I know this is not a complete answer, but thought it would be a hint anyway.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833243/rapidjson-pretty-print-using-json-string-as-input-to-the-writer) link could give you hints about how to use `PrettyWriter`.

You might want to use `reset()`, [RapidJSON documentation](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_writer.html#ac4026d3f14b80d6d7fc10004b1972722) could help.

> This function reset the writer with a new stream and default settings, in order to make a Writer object reusable for output multiple JSONs.

This very documentation provides the following example :

```
Writer<OutputStream> writer(os1);
writer.StartObject();
// ...
writer.EndObject();
writer.Reset(os2);
writer.StartObject();
// ...
writer.EndObject();
```

You could try something like this :

```
StringBuffer JSONData;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(JSONData);
writer.StartObject();
// ...
writer.EndObject();

JSONData.Clear();
writer.Reset(JSONData);
writer.StartObject();
// ...
writer.EndObject();
```

You could even create another output stream and parse it to the reset, just to be sure..

Comment: Yes, but I can't get the reset to work... It won't compile whatever I do

Comment: Unbelievable, this works... I thought I already tried this option but must have made a typo or something. Thanks anyhow